# Represent XML as a HTML in Flex RichEditableText

Tags: html, xml, apache-flex, richeditabletext

I'm developing a word finder of a large text using flex. There I use a RichEditableText to show the whole text and when I find for a word I want to represent all the matching words of that text in a different colour. So I replace all the matching words with html colour changing tags as follows.

```
var replacedContent:String = txtRichBox.Text.replace(new RegExp(txtSearch.text,"g"), "<font color='#ff0000'>"+txtSearch.text+"</font>");
```

And then I set it to the RichEditableText as a HTML as follows.

```
txtRichBox.textFlow = TextConverter.importToFlow(replacedContent, TextConverter.TEXT_FIELD_HTML_FORMAT);
```

This works supper fine.

Now I have a new requirement. There the original text can be a XML. Then if I set the XML with colour changing html tags to the RichEditableText as a HTML everything crash because it takes XML tags also as HTML tags.

So I tried to replace < and > sings of the XML with &lt and &gt.

```
//Replace < with &lt
replacedContent:String = txtFileContent.text.replace(new RegExp("<","g"), "&lt");               

//Replace > with &gt
replacedContent = replacedContent.replace(new RegExp(">","g"), "&gt");
```

Then RichEditableText won't render them back to < and > sings. It shows &lt and &gt as it is.

Can anyone suggest me a solution for this?

Comment: How are you setting the original text on the `txtRichBox` in the first place?

Comment: var displayText:String = "my xml is <root><leaf></leaf></root>";
txtRichBox.text = displayText;

Comment: You code is correct, only mistake is that you have to 
replace < with &lt; instead of &lt Similarly replace > with &gt;
Missing Semicolon was causing all the trouble.